# AMPPS Apache is not starting after Restart/ SHutdown on Macbook Pro

Tags: ampps

Here is the log file

[Tue Jun 09 08:55:52.378786 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2311] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2p PHP/7.3.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jun 09 08:55:52.379156 2020] [core:notice] [pid 2311] AH00094: Command line: '/Applications/AMPPS/apache/bin/httpd'
[Tue Jun 09 08:56:48.228429 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2311] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jun 09 08:58:13.964872 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 637] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2p PHP/7.3.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jun 09 08:58:13.965557 2020] [core:notice] [pid 637] AH00094: Command line: '/Applications/AMPPS/apache/bin/httpd'
[Tue Jun 09 09:29:02.632112 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 802] [client ::1:49585] AH01215: error on line -1 of /Applications/Ampps/extra/ssl/openssl.cnf: /Applications/AMPPS/ampps/softaculous/enduser/index.php, referer: http://localhost/ampps/index.php?act=ampps_domainadd
[Tue Jun 09 09:29:02.632746 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 802] [client ::1:49585] AH01215: 4494323308:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:175:fopen('/Applications/Ampps/extra/ssl/openssl.cnf','rb'): /Applications/AMPPS/ampps/softaculous/enduser/index.php, referer: http://localhost/ampps/index.php?act=ampps_domainadd
[Tue Jun 09 09:29:02.632796 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 802] [client ::1:49585] AH01215: 4494323308:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:bss_file.c:182:: /Applications/AMPPS/ampps/softaculous/enduser/index.php, referer: http://localhost/ampps/index.php?act=ampps_domainadd
[Tue Jun 09 09:29:02.632887 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 802] [client ::1:49585] AH01215: 4494323308:error:0E078072:configuration file routines:DEF_LOAD:no such file:conf_def.c:201:: /Applications/AMPPS/ampps/softaculous/enduser/index.php, referer: http://localhost/ampps/index.php?act=ampps_domainadd
[Tue Jun 09 09:31:06.009748 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 787] [client ::1:49641] AH01215: AH00526: Syntax error on line 25 of /Applications/AMPPS/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:: /Applications/AMPPS/ampps/softaculous/enduser/index.php, referer: http://localhost/ampps/index.php?act=ampps_domainmanage
[Tue Jun 09 09:31:06.010263 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 787] [client ::1:49641] AH01215: Cannot define multiple Listeners on the same IP:port: /Applications/AMPPS/ampps/softaculous/enduser/index.php, referer: http://localhost/ampps/index.php?act=ampps_domainmanage
[Tue Jun 09 09:31:06.823294 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 787] [client ::1:49641] AH01215: AH00526: Syntax error on line 25 of /Applications/AMPPS/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:: /Applications/AMPPS/ampps/softaculous/enduser/index.php, referer: http://localhost/ampps/index.php?act=ampps_domainmanage
[Tue Jun 09 09:31:06.823357 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 787] [client ::1:49641] AH01215: Cannot define multiple Listeners on the same IP:port: /Applications/AMPPS/ampps/softaculous/enduser/index.php, referer: http://localhost/ampps/index.php?act=ampps_domainmanage
[Tue Jun 09 09:31:20.673005 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 639] [client ::1:49651] AH01215: AH00526: Syntax error on line 25 of /Applications/AMPPS/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:: /Applications/AMPPS/ampps/softaculous/enduser/index.php, referer: http://localhost/ampps/index.php?act=ampps_domainmanage
[Tue Jun 09 09:31:20.673247 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 639] [client ::1:49651] AH01215: Cannot define multiple Listeners on the same IP:port: /Applications/AMPPS/ampps/softaculous/enduser/index.php, referer: http://localhost/ampps/index.php?act=ampps_domainmanage
[Tue Jun 09 09:31:41.530751 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 788] [client ::1:49655] AH01215: AH00526: Syntax error on line 25 of /Applications/AMPPS/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:: /Applications/AMPPS/ampps/softaculous/enduser/index.php, referer: http://localhost/ampps/index.php?act=ampps_domainmanage
[Tue Jun 09 09:31:41.531804 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 788] [client ::1:49655] AH01215: Cannot define multiple Listeners on the same IP:port: /Applications/AMPPS/ampps/softaculous/enduser/index.php, referer: http://localhost/ampps/index.php?act=ampps_domainmanage
[Tue Jun 09 09:31:50.528108 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 802] [client ::1:49660] AH01215: error on line -1 of /Applications/Ampps/extra/ssl/openssl.cnf: /Applications/AMPPS/ampps/softaculous/enduser/index.php, referer: http://localhost/ampps/index.php?act=ampps_domainadd
[Tue Jun 09 09:31:50.528339 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 802] [client ::1:49660] AH01215: 4724469356:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:175:fopen('/Applications/Ampps/extra/ssl/openssl.cnf','rb'): /Applications/AMPPS/ampps/softaculous/enduser/index.php, referer: http://localhost/ampps/index.php?act=ampps_domainadd
[Tue Jun 09 09:31:50.528386 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 802] [client ::1:49660] AH01215: 4724469356:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:bss_file.c:182:: /Applications/AMPPS/ampps/softaculous/enduser/index.php, referer: http://localhost/ampps/index.php?act=ampps_domainadd
[Tue Jun 09 09:31:50.528437 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 802] [client ::1:49660] AH01215: 4724469356:error:0E078072:configuration file routines:DEF_LOAD:no such file:conf_def.c:201:: /Applications/AMPPS/ampps/softaculous/enduser/index.php, referer: http://localhost/ampps/index.php?act=ampps_domainadd
[Wed Jun 10 13:33:31.624306 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 637] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

Comment: did you get a fix for this? I'm facing this issue as well :S

Comment: No bro. I switched to Local

Comment: one of the best options we have and it's half baked.

Answer (score 0):

In `Ampps/apache/conf/httpd.conf`

Depends on the version, edit `LoadModule php7_module /Applications/AMPPS/php-7.3/libphp7.so` as `LoadModule php5_module /Applications/AMPPS/php-5.6/libphp5.so`

Then restart AMPPS and switch Apache on. If it works, then edit the php version back to php7.